# getting the id when the data is saved into the database using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Hi i have this form when save, saved into the database. I want that when the data is saved into the database i will get the id on it then displaying it to the next page.
Here's my controller below in my function add_new

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Create_album extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->model('admin_model', 'am');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
      redirect('login');
    }
  }

  public function detail($id){
    return $id;
    $this->data['item'] = $this->am->getItem($id);
    print_r($this->data['item']);exit;
  }

  public function add_new(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'required');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
      $this->data['title'] = 'Create New Album';
      $this->data['logout'] = 'logout';
      $this->data['home'] = 'activities';

      $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
      $this->data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
      $this->data['username'] = $session_data['username'];

      $this->load->view('pages/admin_header', $this->data);
       $this->load->view('content/create_album', $this->data);
      $this->load->view('pages/admin_footer');
    }else{
      $array = array(
                'title'=>$this->input->post('title'),
                'description'=>$this->input->post('description')
                );
      $this->am->saveAlbum($array);
      $id = $this->db->id;
      $this->data['item'] = $this->am->getItem($id);
      return $this->am->saveAlbum($id);
      foreach($this->data['item'] as $item){
        $itemId = $item->id;

      }
      return $itemId;
      redirect('create_album/detail/id/'.$itemId);
    }
  }

  public function index(){
    $this->data['title'] = 'Create Album';
    $this->data['logout'] = 'logout';
    $this->data['home'] = 'activities';

    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $this->data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
    $this->data['username'] = $session_data['username'];

    $this->load->view('pages/admin_header', $this->data);
    $this->load->view('content/create_album', $this->data);
    $this->load->view('pages/admin_footer');
  }

}
```

my model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class Admin_model extends CI_Model{
  public function getItem($id){
    return $this->db->select('item.id,
                         item.parent_id,
                         item.title,
                         item.description,
                         item.filename
                        '
                        )
                 ->from('item')
                 ->where('item.id', $id)
                 ->get()->result_object();
     $this->db->get('item');

  }


}
```

?>

Can someone help me figured this out? i want to get the ID when the data is saved. Any help is muchly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use this

```
$this->db->insert_id(); // Returns your row id.
```

Here how your controller should look like

```
public function add_new(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'required');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
      $this->data['title'] = 'Create New Album';
      $this->data['logout'] = 'logout';
      $this->data['home'] = 'activities';

      $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
      $this->data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
      $this->data['username'] = $session_data['username'];

      $this->load->view('pages/admin_header', $this->data);
       $this->load->view('content/create_album', $this->data);
      $this->load->view('pages/admin_footer');
    }else{
      $array = array(
                'title'=>$this->input->post('title'),
                'description'=>$this->input->post('description')
                );
      $this->am->saveAlbum($array);
      $id = $this->db->id;
      $this->data['item'] = $this->am->getItem($id);
      return $this->am->saveAlbum($id);
      foreach($this->data['item'] as $item){
        $itemId = $item->id;

      }
      return $itemId;
      redirect('create_album/detail/id/'.$this->db->insert_id()); // here?
    }
  }
```

Comment: hey thank this works im adding the $this->db->insert_id() code on it

Comment: Glad to hear that! don't forget to choose the correct answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

Think you're probably looking for the insert_id() query helper function. You can see info about it in the [Codeigniter docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html).

Answer (score 0):

When PHP hits `return` in a function it does just that, return a value, and it exits the function. Code following the return will not be executed. Read about it [on the docs page](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.return.php)

Example:

```
public function detail($id){
  return $id;
  echo 'here';
}
```

You will never get 'here' to echo, since you have already returned a value in your `function()`.

Again this applies twice in your code, once here:

```
return $itemId;
redirect('create_album/detail/id/'.$this->db->insert_id());
```

and again here:

```
$this->data['item'] = $this->am->getItem($id);
return $this->am->saveAlbum($id);
```

If you want the insert id you are going to have to return it from `$this->am->saveAlbum();` Assign that to a variable and pass it to your redirect.

There are quite a few other issues, but that should help to get you started.